# How to read a file outside main/working folder in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, fs

I have created a server on node and I can render a HTML page if that page is inside the working folder.

However , when I change the path to a different folder , I can't render the page and I understand this has something to do with the path I am assigning.

This is the path to the main/working folder :

```
function OnRequest(request , response){
   fs.readFile('./index.html' , null , function(error , data){
       if (error){
           response.writeHead(404);
           console.log("Ups, something is wrong :/");

       } else {
           response.writeHead(200)
           response.write(data)
           response.end();
       }
   })
};
```

And this is the path to the folder outside the main folder :

```
function OnRequest(request , response){
   fs.readFile('c:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Projectos\7 - Site da Pintura\Galeria.html' , null , function(error , data){
       if (error){
           response.writeHead(404);
           console.log("Ups, something is wrong :/");

       } else {
           response.writeHead(200)
           response.write(data)
           response.end();
       }
   })
};
```

This is the error I got :

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Projectos\8 - Criar um Servidor\UsersSimonDesktopProjectos - Site da PinturaGaleria.html'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\Projectos\\8 - Criar um Servidor\\UsersSimonDesktopProjectos\x07 - Site da PinturaGaleria.html'
}
```

This makes me think that I need to change the path inside that object because obviously it is wrong. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with relative or absolute paths, it's with string escaping backslashes (`\`). In other words, you cannot simply use backlashes in string, as they are meant for escape characters like `\'` (an quote without closing your string encapsulation), or `\n` (new line).

To use a backslash in a string, you either need to write `\\`:

```
const path = `C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\Projectos\\7 - Site da Pintura\\Galeria.html`
```

Or use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to prevent your backslashes escaping:

```
const path = String.raw`C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Projectos\7 - Site da Pintura\Galeria.html`
```

In either case, both paths should work fine as long as the file exists and within your read permissions.

Comment: Oh wow !! Simple solution eheh , that's good!! So I simply can not use a backslash alone like that , hein !!

Comment: That's right, In most environments, backslash is used as an escape character. Have a look at some [JavaScript examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript).

Answer (score -1):

It seems I have found a solution. :

I assume one of the problems was that **- even though I was giving the full path to the file I wanted to open in the readfFile() method -** that path was being added to an already existent path in some object , resulting in this :

```
path: 'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\Projectos\\8 - Criar um Servidor\\UsersSimonDesktopProjectos\x07 - Site da PinturaGaleria.html'
}
```

By using the method path.resolve() the issue seems to be gone and I can now load the HTML file outside from my home folder without even having to write the full path :

```
path.resolve('../7 - Site da Pintura/Galeria.html')
```

And it worked :

```
function OnRequest(request , response){
   fs.readFile(path.resolve('../7 - Site da Pintura/Galeria.html'), null , function(error , data){
       if (error){
           response.writeHead(404);
           console.log(error);

       } else {
           response.writeHead(200)
           response.write(data)
           response.end();
       }
   })
};
```